# Почему при работе с копией словаря в оригинале тоже происходят изменения?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cipher = {
        'А': [760, 128, 350, 201, 9],
        'Б': [101, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'В': [210, 1060, 9, 9, 9],
        'Г': [351, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Д': [129, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Е': [761, 130, 802, 352, 9],
        'Ж': [102, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'З': [753, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'И': [762, 211, 131, 9, 9],
        'К': [754, 764, 9, 9, 9],
        'Л': [123, 354, 9, 9, 9],
        'М': [755, 742, 9, 9, 9],
        'Н': [763, 756, 212, 9, 9],
        'О': [757, 213, 765, 133, 353, 9],
        'П': [743, 766, 9, 9, 9],
        'Р': [134, 532, 9, 9, 9],
        'С': [800, 767, 105, 9, 9],
        'Т': [759, 135, 214, 9, 9],
        'У': [544, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ф': [560, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Х': [768, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ц': [545, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ч': [215, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ш': [103, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Щ': [752, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ъ': [561, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ы': [136, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ь': [562, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Э': [750, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Ю': [570, 9, 9, 9, 9],
        'Я': [216, 104, 9, 9, 9],
        ' ': [751, 769, 758, 801, 84, 9],
    }
    
    copy_cipher = cipher.copy()
    print(copy_cipher)
    print(cipher)
    copy_cipher['О'].pop(0)
    print(copy_cipher)
    print(cipher)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: Надо ещё побольше словарь в вопрос засунуть, чтобы ещё удобнее было искать нужное место в выводе

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Вы копируете элементы словаря, которые являются *ссылками* на списки. Сами списки при этом не копируются, копируются ссылки на них. Чтобы скопировать сами списки нужно использовать `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy 
copy_cipher = deepcopy(cipher)
```